# Exception when calling "DownloadFile" with 2 argument(s): "Exception error during a WebClient request."

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

I created a .bat file to download from a link but it is throwing the error. What I am doing wrong ?

```
@echo off

rem ============================================================================
rem -- Set up environment ------------------------------------------------------
rem ============================================================================

set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
set CONTENT_FOLDER=%SCRIPT_DIR%Unreal/CarlaUE4/Content/Carla


rem ============================================================================
rem -- Get the last version to download ----------------------------------------
rem ============================================================================

if not exist "%CONTENT_FOLDER%" mkdir "%CONTENT_FOLDER%"

set CONTENT_ID = BP_Camera
set CONTENT_LINK=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1L72sa5Egy1nJbv_7L75nbUV0vjGxzvsK
set CONTENT_FILE=%CONTENT_FOLDER%/%CONTENT_ID%.uasset

)

rem ============================================================================
rem -- Download the content ----------------------------------------------------
rem ============================================================================

echo Downloading "%CONTENT_LINK%"...
powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%CONTENT_LINK%', 'BP_Camera.uasset')"
```

Now i am getting a file which is less size than the normal one. Am I doing any wrong here?

Comment: Is this the _actual_ code you are using? Because the error message doesn't match up. The PowerShell command uses undefined variables `$URL` and `$Path`.

Comment: My bad..i kind of changed the variables in between...can you check the edited code...Now the problem is that i am getting no error but the file is not downloading completely.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment may solve your issue by changing the `$URL` and `$Path` to match your `CONTENT_FOLDER` and `CONTENT_LINK`.

Something that has helped me in the past is to use single quotes for my URLs like below:

```
set CONTENT_LINK='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1L72sa5Egy1nJbv_7L75nbUV0vjGxzvsK'
```

Comment: It does not work for me unfortunately

Comment: Try the below URL. This is using Google's API to do the download. It is based on this document site https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get. I just used the file id from your code example, but you can change the file id to whatever file you want.
```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1L72sa5Egy1nJbv_7L75nbUV0vjGxzvsK
```